# Type for with same field names but different types

Tags: typescript, types, record

Suppose I have a type like the following:

```js
type Thing = {
    aField: string;
    anotherField: number;
    // ...
}
```

I would like to make a "mask" type that has all the same fields, but with boolean values:

```js
type ThingMask = {
    aField: boolean;
    anotherField: boolean;
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically without having to hardcode the mask type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type ThingMask = { [K in keyof Thing]: boolean };
/* type ThingMask = {
    aField: boolean;
    anotherField: boolean;
} */
```

Note that by default this will also copy the `readonly` and optional (`?`) modifiers from the original type to the mapped type.  If you don't want that to happen you cabn [alter this behavior](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers) by using modifiers like `-readonly` or `-?`.  But since you didn't ask about that I won't go into it more.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[link to code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8CwAoKQqAQwDEEIAbAEwC4oBnYAJ2RQG58iSkB7YOBGbkqdKEgCuAWwBGQzgSIB6JVAB0G-AF8o+fKEixEqALLEGAawzYoAbQDSUZFAsQQvAGZG2AXXozeXkoIYiQoLQUlACooA2h4NjNLa1xFQjIKGn9A4NCFblD+QWFMsQCgkKQFHSilIA)

Comment: Is there a way of making that mapped type generic? Like... type ThingMask<T> = { [K in keyof T]: boolean } ?
EDIT: yes, it works (useful for Angular2+ FormGroups)